# Monitoring DBCP2 connection pool with JMX

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, apache-commons-dbcp

I read from DBCP2 documentation that this new version supports JMX monitoring for connection pool, but I couldn't find any example which shows actual usage.

I have a simple JDBC based java application which uses dbcp2 to create a connection pool which is used by a simple query service, and I want to monitor these connection via another tool like VisualVM using JMX.
DBCP2's `BasicDataSource` has methods like [setJmxName()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setJmxName-java.lang.String-)
which I don't see any usage for that, and don't know how to use it.

If someone is not familiar with JDBC, you can read about it [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Improved the question format to make it a bit easier to understand. Added some resources pointing to the JDBC documentation for others to easier follow up on what the topic is focusing on.

Comment: I had tons of issue with DBCP2 in Production with the high number of threads, I decided to use C3P0 which is working perfectly, plus it had a very good JMX implementation.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't found any documentation either, but I have figured a few things out by digging through the source code.

You just need to create a `BasicDataSource` or `BasicManagedDataSource` object, like you normally would, and then call the `setJmxName()` method.  The `DataSource` will then register itself with the platform's MBean server when you call the `getConnection()` method and unregister itself when you call the `close()` method.

---

Setting a JMX name of `"org.apache.dbcp:DataSource=mydbname"` works, an example Apache uses for unit tests can be [found here](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/7bc446a2ebd453e98a70777042ffa49aecdb1302/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/TestPStmtPooling.java#L138).

Comment: The Object Name Syntax is described here: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/best-practices-jsp-136021.html.