# Monitoring DB connection pool status using JMX?

Tags: java, database, connection, connection-pooling, jmx

A DB is created using apache commons DBCP 2.0 not able to find MBean names as part of JMX to monitor the connection pool related data how to enable it if it is not enabled by default?

Comment: I am using this dependancy: 

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337147/175554 may help